# Dynamic load content with tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am beginner in JS. I have dynamic html load from php (jquery).
In result from php I have this html:

```
<img title="Mleko" class="info-tooltip" style="max-height:15px" src="assets/ikonki/mleko.png">
<img title="Jaja" class="info-tooltip" style="max-height:15px" src="assets/ikonki/jajka.png">
```

This is my tooltip code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".info-tooltip").tooltip({
            tooltipClass: "tooltip-styling",
            position: {
                my: "left bottom",
                at: "center top-10",
                collision: "none"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And tooltip is not working :( It's not showing.
I have in my page Bootstrap and jquery.

When I add this images normally, in html code - this work fine.

Problem is only with images (tooltip)  dynamic load from php.

How can I repair it?

Answer (score 0):

You say the first HTML example is dynamically loaded - I assume you mean that you're doing this using AJAX. As such you need to call `.tooltip()` on the new content *after* the AJAX request completes and the new HTML is added to the DOM.

To do this use a promise or the `success` callback, something like this:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '/yourpage',
  data: { foo: bar },
  success: function(html) {
    $('#container').append(html);

    // instantiate tooltips here...
    $("#container .info-tooltip").tooltip({
      tooltipClass: "tooltip-styling",
      position: {
        my: "left bottom",
        at: "center top-10",
        collision: "none"
      }
    });
  }
});
```